# I am trying to color specific characters individually. (Console, C#, .Net.)

Tags: c#, .net, console

So I am trying to color individual charactrs E.G "0 is allways red 1 is allways blue 2 is allways green etc." I am using a nuget package called "MathNet.Numerics.FSharp." And from that i am using BigRational (a BigRational is a infanate bit int.) in a Console.WriteLine  E.G "Console.WriteLine(i);" and I am makeing a program with extreamly large numbers and I want to color the numbers to so I can look at the numbers and look for patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CharacterColoring` function that I created can be used both singly and in a `loop`.

It is used in the loop as follows:

Output:

[image: Output]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void CharacterColoring(char YourChar, ConsoleColor YourFavoriteColor)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = YourFavoriteColor;
            Console.Write(YourChar);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string YourText = "Hello world 1 2";
            for (int i = 0; i < YourText.Length; i++)
            {
                if (YourText[i] == '1')
                {
                    CharacterColoring(YourText[i], ConsoleColor.Red);
                }
                else if (YourText[i] == '2')
                {
                    CharacterColoring(YourText[i], ConsoleColor.Blue);
                }
                else
                {
                    CharacterColoring(YourText[i], ConsoleColor.Green);
                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Tested in:

`Visual Studio 2017`, `.NET Framework 4.5.2`, `Console App`

Comment: So that probably would work for an int but I will need to convert "for (int i = 0; i < YourText.Length; i++)" that part from using an int to a BigRational wich might be hard but I think I may be able to do it. il get back to you when I have know if I can convert it but thanks for the help.